# how to make negative numbers into positive

Tags: c

I am having the negative floating point number as:

```
a = -0.340515;
```

to convert this into positive number I used the abs() method as:

```
a = abs(a);
```

the result is `a = 0.000000;`

But I need the result as `0.340515`.

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Why is this tagged Objective C when it's about C++?

Comment: @Catfish_Man: it's actually about C.

Comment: multiply by -1 maybe?

Comment: @RezoMegrelidze's suggestion is 100% okay in the event you don't want to include an entire library just for a single purpose. Granted, you must be 100% sure that you're dealing with a negative number: `t1 = t1 < 0 ? -1*t1 : t1;` I'd assume that's all that `abs `family does in this scenario. | Alternatively, you can subtract the negative value from 0:  `t1 = t1 < 0 ? 0-t1 : t1;` Given that, the standard solution is still favorable as it's more likely to be immediately clear. Do as you please, but keep that in mind.

Comment: I guess the type of `a` is `int`.

Answer (score 99):

`abs()` is for integers only. For floating point, use `fabs()` (or one of the `fabs()` line with the correct precision for whatever a actually is)

Comment: If one is not too worried about dirty stuff, one can also do: `if(a<0.0) a=-a;`.

Comment: @Romain: I always marvel at how people shun standard solutions for something self-coded. What does your code have in advantage over the solution provided by Jason?

Comment: @DevSolar I was young and foolish by then.

Comment: @Romain: Your code does not work correctly for negative zero, i.e. when a == -0.0;

Answer (score 50):

You have to use: 
 
 abs() for **int** 
 fabs() for **double** 
 fabsf() for **float**
 Above function will also work but you can also try something like this.

```
    if(a<0)
    {
         a=-a;
    }
```

Comment: You can try, yes. But should you?

Comment: + 1 fabsf() for float. More correct than the accepted answer.

Comment: if (a<0) a=-a; does not work correctly for negative zero, i.e. when a == -0.0;

Answer (score 20):

Use `float fabsf (float n)` for `float` values.

Use `double fabs (double n)` for `double` values.

Use `long double fabsl(long double)` for `long double` values.

Use `abs(int)` for `int` values.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in mathematics to convert a negative number to a positive number you just need to **multiple** the negative number by -1;

Then your solution could be like this:

```
a = a * -1;
```

or shorter:

```
a *= -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a *= (-1);
```

problem solved. If there is a smaller solution for a problem, then why you guys going for a complex solution. Please direct people to use the base logic also because then only the people can train their programming logic.

Comment: because `abs()` is more useful in some cases, like when you have a number that can be both positive and negative, in this case multipling by -1 will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
floor a;
floor b;
a = -0.340515;
```

so what to do?

```
b = 65565 +a;
a = 65565 -b;
```

or

```
if(a < 0){
a = 65565-(65565+a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int makePositiveSUM(int a,int b);

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        cout<<makePositiveSUM(x,y)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int makePositiveSUM(int a,int b){
    if(a>b){
        return a-b;
    }
    else {
        return b-a;
    }
}

    enter code here
    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this should work whatever sign *a* has, subject the power fits the int boundaries: a=sqrt(a*a)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], please explain the relevant advantage which your solution achieves over existing upvoted answers and why you consider the disadvantages of your solution negligible. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: That's definitely a bad advice. It's inefficient from performance perspective and has no advantages over simpler solutions already proposed here

Answer (score -1):

this is the only way i can think of doing it.

```
//positive to minus
int a = 5; // starting with 5 to become -5
int b = int a * 2; // b = 10
int c = a - b; // c = - 5;
std::cout << c << endl;
//outputs - 5


 //minus to positive
int a = -5; starting with -5 to become 5
int b = a * 2; 
// b = -10
int c = a + b 
// c = 5
std::cout << c << endl;
//outputs 5
```

Function examples

```
int b = 0;
int c = 0;


int positiveToNegative (int a) {
    int b = a * 2;
    int c = a - b;
    return c;
}

int negativeToPositive (int a) { 
    int b = a * 2;
    int c = a + b;
    return c; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to use strange hard commands, when you can use:

```
if(a < 0)
    a -= 2a;
```

The if statement obviously only applies when you aren't sure if the number will be positive or negative.

Otherwise you'll have to use this code:

```
a = abs(a) // a is an integer
a = fabs(a) // a is declared as a double
a = fabsf(a) // a is declared as a float (C++ 11 is able to use fabs(a) for floats instead of fabs)
```

To activate C++ 11 (if you are using Code::Blocks, you have to:

1. Open up Code::Blocks (recommended version: 13.12).
2. Go to Settings -> Compiler.
3. Make sure that the compiler you use is GNU GCC Compiler.
4. Click Compiler Settings, and inside the tab opened click Compiler Flags
5. Scroll down until you find: Have g++ follow the C++ 11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]. Check that and then hit OK button.
6. Restart Code::Blocks and then you are good to go!

After following these steps, you should be able to use fabs(a) for floats instead of fabsf(a), which was used only for C99 or less! (Even C++ 98 could allow you to use fabs instead of fabsf :P)

Comment: `if(a < 0)
    a -= a;` urhm.... wouldnt this end in `if (a < 0) a*=2;`? What is not what OP trys to acv