# Is DBL_MIN the smallest positive double?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, numeric

**Q:** Is DBL_MIN the smallest positive double?

The code below seems to anwser this question with no. But if this is true, how is DBL_MIN the defined and what is its use or purpose.

Platform: Windows7 & Visual Studio 2013

```
double next_to_zero = std::nextafter(0.0,DBL_MIN);
bool b =  DBL_MIN <= next_to_zero;
std::cout << std::boolalpha 
          << "is dbl_min the smallest representable double? "
          << b << '\n';

std::cout << std::setprecision(56)
          << "dbl_min = " << DBL_MIN << '\n'
          << "next to zero = " << next_to_zero;
```

outputs:

> is dbl_min the smallest representable double? false
>
> dbl_min = 2.2250738585072013830902327173324040642192159804623318306e-308
>
> next to zero = 4.9406564584124654417656879286822137236505980261432476443e-324

Comment: C++ std::numeric_limits::min documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm restricting this answer, perhaps unnecessarily, to IEEE754 floating point.

`DBL_MIN` is not allowed to be a *subnormal* number.

But `std::nextafter` is allowed to return a *subnormal* number.

Hence the return value of the latter could be less than `DBL_MIN`.

For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: So, DBL_MIN is the smallest normal double value?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, on Intel, the floating point registers are 80-bit long double, and can hold even more values.

Comment: "Some systems handle denormal values in hardware, in the same way as normal values. Others leave the handling of denormal values to system software, only handling normal values and zero in hardware. Handling denormal values in software always leads to a significant decrease in performance."

Comment: "When denormal values are entirely computed in hardware, implementation techniques exist to allow their processing at speeds comparable to normal numbers; however, the speed of computation is significantly reduced on many modern processors; in extreme cases, instructions involving denormal operands may run as much as 100 times slower.

This speed difference can be a security risk.
...
Some applications need to contain code to avoid denormal numbers, either to maintain accuracy, or in order to avoid the performance penalty in some processors."

Answer (score 5):

> Is `DBL_MIN` the smallest positive double?

Not certainly.
`DBL_MIN` is the smallest positive *normal* `double`.

`DBL_TRUE_MIN` is the smallest positive  `double` (since C++17).  It will be smaller than `DBL_MIN` when `double` supports [subnormals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number#Terminology).

Comment: I can't see a `DBL_TRUE_MIN` definition anywhere, though.

Comment: @AlexisWilke `DBL_TRUE_MIN` --> [minimum positive value of `double`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits)

Comment: Ah. It's available on Ubuntu 20.04 (g++ v9.3). It's not yet available in 18.04.