# When to specify a custom epsilon in Delphi's SameValue function?

Tags: delphi

I recently came across the `SameValue` function to compare floating-point numbers. I noticed that we can optionally specify an epsilon value for this function.

From the documentation, I understand that Delphi provides default epsilon values (`SingleEpsilon`, `DoubleEpsilon`, `ExtendedEpsilon`) based on the data type of the floating-point values being compared.

```
function SameValue(const A, B: Single; Epsilon: Single = 0): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Double; Epsilon: Double = 0): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Extended; Epsilon: Extended = 0): Boolean; overload;
```

My questions are:

1. In general use-cases, is it reliable to use the SameValue function without specifying a custom epsilon?
2. Are there specific scenarios where one must or should provide a custom epsilon value?
3. If providing a custom epsilon, what's a good strategy to determine an appropriate value based on the context?

Would appreciate insights or best practices!

Comment: Without attempting to write a full answer, just some quick spontaneous thoughts: (1) the default implementation for Epsilon = 0 seems just fine, (2) one clear case (but probably you were looking for more obscure cases) is where you yourself simply define that everything that is within e.g. 0.5 or 1 or even 10 from each other is the same, (3) if your float values are going to be stored in a database table, then in some scenario it could perhaps be useful to choose an Epsilon that makes your SameValue work (roughly) with the same precision as the data type in that database table.

Comment: For example, the money type in SQL server uses 4 decimals, so an Epsilon of 0.0001 or 0.0000999 might be useful. (Although you probably shouldn't use the money type like that, it's essentially an integer value. But, still, as a theoretical example.)

Comment: This entirely depends on your application. You may want to buy a textbook about numerical algorithms or scientific computing.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes I agree but i read somewhere that using samevalue, comparevalue, etc without specifying an Epsilon value is a non sense. I just want to dig in it to know why ?

Comment: I'd say in quite a few every-day instances a plain `SameValue(A, B)` is good enough, even though the semantics may not be precisely right. However, IIRC, David has some rather strong opinions about `SameValue` that he may have time to repeat here.

Comment: yes would love to hear it's point of view :) @DavidHeffernan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the issue with the default epsilon supplied by delphi is that, in a chain of operations, the cumulative rounding error can outgrow the default epsilon. So, the more operations you apply to a value, the less likely SameValue will behave as desired with the default epsilon.

As for a strategy for determining a custom epsilon.  I personnaly find that using a value that is 1 order of magnitude lower than what we could call the "base meaningful unit"(BMU) of the context is decent.

For example, if we're talking about a retail USD price, the BMU would be 0.01$ so I'd use 0.001 as an epsilon. But then, unitary prices are often required to have a 4 decimals precision, in which case the BMU would be 0.0001$. In that situation, I'd use 0.00001 as the epsilon.

There are most likely contexts where the idea of a BMU doesn't apply. In those cases, I'm not sure how I would go about selecting a custom epsilon. Using the default one would probably be the safest bet.

As everything floating point related, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) remains a "must read"

EDIT: Andreas brings a good point. Delphi uses by default an epsilon that is at least *FloatType*Resolution. For Double(Other types have similar situation), that value is 1E-12, but Double can have values of the order of 1E-308 ([or even smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746861/is-dbl-min-the-smallest-positive-double)). So, when working with very small values, an explicit epsilon would also be required.

Comment: hmm yes that make sense, cumulative rounding error can outgrow the default epsilon. thanks!

Comment: Although this A makes perfect sense, it doesn't address all issues related to `SameValue`. Remember that `SameValue(x, y, ε)` is *not* defined as simply `Abs(x - y) <= ε` but also takes into account the magnitudes of `x` and `y`. So very interesting things can happen if `x` and `y` are of different orders of magnitude and/or very close to zero.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'm currently looking at the source code of System.Math.SameValue of Delphi 11.3, and it _is_ defined as (basically) `Abs(x - y) <= ε` . (Instead of using `Abs`, they are inverting operand to ensure positive value, i.e `x-y` or `y-x`). So I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @KenBourassa: Sorry, I meant to write that the default (omitted) epsilon causes such a consideration. You're absolutely right that you get a plain `Abs(x - y) <= ε` if you specify your own (positive) epsilon. If you don't specify it explicitly, you get `Epsilon := Max(Min(Abs(A), Abs(B)) * ExtendedResolution, ExtendedResolution);` which may or may not be suitable.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Good point.  But, from my understanding, it's just really an issue if both values are very small. Added some details in that regard.